# How do I hide contact name from whatsapp notification on iphone5

Tags: iphone, contacts, notifications, privacy, whatsapp.app

I saw someone's iphone5 whatsapp notification pop up with only the whatsapp badge and the word "message" but I can't figure out how to do that on my iphone5

Comment: There's quite a few questions here regarding WhatsApp and notifications.  Look at the question links on the right side of this page where people want to see the notification name and do the opposite of those answers to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

On your iPhone go to Settings > Notifications > WhatsApp > scroll down and you'll see "Show Previews" > And change that.

Also in WhatsApp settings. Click on Notifications. The toggle "Show Preview" off.

That should only show the senders name and not the context of the message.

You can also turn of show on lock screen for WhatsApp in iPhone notification settings for added privacy.

Comment: I would like to not show the contact name. Only the whatsapp badge and the word "message" as i saw it on somebody else's phone similar to mine.

Comment: Thats something whatsapp controls.